# Spring data Neo4j fetch relationships

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using spring-data-neo4j V4 and look for solution how to fetch entities which are not directly connected to the loaded entity. To explain:

I do have 3 entities in my neo4j database.

```
@NodeEntity(label="membership")
public class Membership extends AbstractEntity{

    public Membership(){ }

    private String membershipId;

    @Relationship(type = "IN_YEAR", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Year> year = new HashSet<>();

    //getter+setter

}

@NodeEntity(label="year")
public class Year extends AbstractEntity{

    public Year(){}

    private String name;
    private String membershipId;

    @Relationship(type = "IN_MONTH", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING )
    private Set<Month> month = new HashSet<>();

    //getter+setter
}

@NodeEntity(label="month")
public class Month extends AbstractEntity{

    private String name;

    //getter+setter
}
```

When i call my `MembershipRepository` and load a `Membership` by Id:

```
membershipRepository.findByMembershipId(id);
```

the `year` entities will be fetched but the `month` entities not.
Can anybody tell what is the best or recommended way to load the `month` entities when loading the `membership` entity? As written in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/ the `@Fetch` is obsolete since version 4 so I need another solution.

EDIT:
I read in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/ the workaround for fetch, just use the `load` methods from the `Neo4jTemplate`.
So I load the months for every year by:

```
Set<Year> fetchedYear = new HashSet<>();
for(Year year : ms.getYear()){
    fetchedYear.add(neo4jTemplate.load(Year.class, year.getId(), 1));
}   
ms.setYear(fetchedYear);
```

But is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option would be to use loadByProperty and set the loading depth to 2.

Example:

```
neo4jTemplate.loadByProperty(Membership.class, "membershipId", value, 2);
```

This is available for SDN-4.1.0-Snapshot

But if you do not want to load a Membership with depth 2 because too much of your graph will be loaded (from other relationships) then I think you could construct a cypher query (using OPTIONAL MATCH), execute it with the neo4jTemplate and retrieve the Object which will then be automatically mapped due to the “smartObjectMapping".

Example:

```
String query = "MATCH (n:Membership{membershipId:{id})-[r]-(m) OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Year)-[e]-(x) RETURN n,r,m,e,x";
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("id",value);
Result result = neo4jTemplate.query(query,map);
```

now n in the Result should contain all mapped relationships